# How do I serialize a has-many-through relationship with Ember's JSONAPIAdapter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I have three models: `User`, `Group`, and `Membership`. A User has many Groups through Memberships. I have a form to invite a new user and assign them to zero or more groups all at once.

#### What I Want

The JSON I expect to send to the server for `POST /users` looks like

```
{
  data: {
    type: 'user',
    id: null,
    attributes: { name: 'Sam Sample' }
  },
  relationships: {
    memberships: {
      data: [
        {
          type: 'membership',
          id: null,
          relationships: {
            group: {
              data: {
                type: 'group',
                id: 12345
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'membership',
          id: null,
          relationships: {
            group: {
              data: {
                type: 'group',
                id: 67890
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### What I Tried

I tried adding `serialize: true` to the relevant serializers:

```
// serializer:user
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    memberships: { serialize: true }
  }
})

// serializer:membership
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    group: { serialize: true }
  }
})
```

That gets me *some* of the JSON I expect, but not all of it. Specifically, I get the `membership` objects, but not the `group`s within them

```
{
  data: {
    type: 'user',
    id: null,
    attributes: { name: 'Sam Sample' }
  },
  relationships: {
    memberships: {
      data: [
        {
          type: 'membership',
          id: null
        },
        {
          type: 'membership',
          id: null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is that json-api valid? i thought relationship should contain resource identifier. this part if the spec is not specified.

Comment: I'm struggling with this myself.

Comment: I've heard of folks using a clientId field where the ember app assigns a temporary id on the model so that it can be reassociated with the new model returned after the post request

Comment: > i thought relationship should contain resource identifier

Actually, I need `id: null`. I've edited to add that.